# Group similar items in list in the same sequence in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, group-by

I have a list with duplicate items. I have to display similar items together in the same sequence. I tried sort but it changes the sequence by sorting it in asc / des order.

For example:-

I have a list like below

```
tbl1_aaa
tbl1_bbb
chk2_ccc
drp3_ddd
tbl1_eee
txt4_fff
chk2_ggg
```

I need to *group* it considering the string before `'_'` like the below

```
tbl1_aaa
tbl1_bbb
tbl1_eee
chk2_ccc
chk2_ggg
drp3_ddd
txt4_fff
```

Can this be achieved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try *grouping* with a help of `GroupBy` and then *flatten* groups with `SelectMany`:

```
var result = list
  .GroupBy(item => item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf('_') + 1))
  .SelectMany(group => group)
  .ToList();

// Let's have a look:
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
tbl1_aaa
tbl1_bbb
tbl1_eee
chk2_ccc
chk2_ggg
drp3_ddd
txt4_fff
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ioNWWv

Comment: i have edited my question. no 2 items are similar. only a part of it matches. can we group it accordingly considering only the first part of the item.

Comment: it is displaying the same result. no changes when compared with my original list

Comment: @Aswini: please, check if you've modified `GroupBy` (or just copy + paste my code and see)

Comment: i still get the same lst as my original one. my exact item in the list is in this format '(tbl1_aaa) technical'

Comment: @Aswini: Could you provide the test *as it is*? And then the desired outcome for this *exact test*?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ with SQL format like this:

```
  List<string> str = 
    new List<string> { "tbl1", "tbl1", "chk2", "drp3", "tbl1", "txt4", "chk2" };
    str = (from s in str 
           group s by s into ag 
           from g in ag orderby g descending select g).ToList();

Update

    List<string> str = 
new List<string> { "tbl1_aaa", "tbl1_bbb", "chk2_ccc", "drp3_ddd", "tbl1_eee", "txt4_fff", "chk2_ggg" };
                str = (from s in str
                       group s by s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('_') + 1) into ag
                    from g in ag orderby g descending
                    select g).ToList();
```

Comment: This is changing the sequence of the item order

Comment: i can just use sort. but i dont want to sort the items in any order. i just want to group similar ones in same sequence.